# Raspberry Pi w/ Archlinux: C program freezes when writing to serial port

Tags: serial-port, arduino, raspberry-pi

I've got an Arduino attached to my Raspberry Pi which runs on Archlinux ARM, and I'm using a simple C program that reads and writes to the serial bus to the Arduino (/dev/ttyACM0).

This worked fine as long as I had the Arduino attached to my PC, but when I use the Raspberry Pi instead, reading still works but writing will freeze as soon as the buffer is flushed or the connection closed.

This very basic C example atually causes such a freeze:
If the fflush() command is in there it will freeze there, if it's removed then it'll instead freeze at fclose().

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("/dev/ttyACM0", "wb");
..error handling..
fprintf(fp, "%c", 'B'); /* write the character 'B' to the serial port)
fflush(fp); /* optional, if more write operations follow, in an actual program */
fclose(fp);
```

Reading from the bus works fine.
I also tried the program "minicom" as it is often suggested for testing serial connections, and it yielded the same results: Sending from Arduino to Pi is fine, trying to type in a character on Pi side -> freeze.

I have tried lots of different stuff on opening/configuring such as replacing the simple fopen() sequence shown above by:

```
fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
if (fd == -1) {
  printf("couldn't open serial port.\n");
  return -1;
}
fp = fdopen(fd, "w");
```

and also changing some canonical something parameters (not sure what I'm actually doing there) but to no avail. It will just keep freezing as soon as the Pi tries to write a character to the serial bus.

I've also made sure that all TTYs are unused on the Pi via

```
ps -ef | grep -i tty
```

to exclude any silly getty/agetty interference.
And I've tested it without any additional hardware plugged in, to make sure that it isn't a symptom caused by the power supply not being able to sustain everything connected to the Pi, as someone suggested to me.

By now I'm totally out of ideas except that the hardware is maybe just faulty. But that's hard to believe, is it? (And I don't have a replacement to test.)

UPDATE:
When using above alternate sequence and removing the fcntl() line, the C program no longer freezes on writing:

```
fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if (fd == -1) {
  printf("couldn't open serial port.\n");
  return -1;
}
fp = fdopen(fd, "w");
```

So at first I was happy, but actually the written data never arrives on the Arduino side! :(

Answer (score 0):

first of all, rasPI cannot work directy from a PC USB as they are limited below the rasPI need, so you need an external power supply (i used one from a smartphone, now i'm using a plugged usb hub)

Changes are that plugging your arduino drains too much power, and the arduino's and rasPi chip beave randomly. Check if, when the program freeze, the serial port used is still there (check with dmesg, maybe it has been plugged/uplugged)

If your power source are fine, then explain what you mean by freeze; the rasPi freeze or only the code. Eiter case it is a fault on the rasPi side, try updating OS and firmware; the serial does not check if someone is reciving, so flush should only hang the time necessary to write the buffer, even if no one is reading.

remeber that close(), will always call flush(), so use flush() only if really needed. (like in this case, for debugging purpoise :) )

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Only the C program freezes, the Pi seems totally fine. The serial port remains present, dmesg reports nothing at all when the freeze occurs (and I did a "watch -n 0.1 'ls /dev/ttyACM0'" too just in case ;). I always have the OS (Archlinux) updated (it updates firmware too). This same problem also occurred with Raspbian Wheezy, which I used previously.

Comment: what's the powr source of the rasp and of the arduino? did you know arduino "think" at 5v and rasp at 3,3v, so you need a logic level traslator or you can damage te raspi?

Comment: The Arduino is just connected to the Pi via USB, not via actual electronic pins and circuits :) The Arduino (Leonardo) is powered via the same USB, while the Pi is powered by a standard 5V/1A PSU via its Micro-USB connector. The electric circuits that the Arduino controls are all connected via opto-couplers to keep them galvanically separate, for maximum safety.

Comment: I tried powering the Arduino with a dedicated PSU (9V/2A) instead of via USB, to no avail. The same thing happens.

Comment: urm, permission are fine? also seems lik someone else has your problem: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?&t=43482
how much Ampere does you PSU give?
also what appen if you use picocom or some other pre-build program?

Comment: I gave full permissions for testing purpose (666) and it didn't help. Arduino PSU gave 2A while Pi PSU gives 1A. Minicom froze when I tried to write a character, reading form Arduino worked fine, same as my program basically. After I changed my program in the way I updated my question today, minicom doesn't freeze either anymore, but as I wrote, the 'sent' character never arrives on the Arduino. :(

Comment: pay attention, you do not freeze at write(), but when flush() is called, that's why your last code does not freeze up and does not write anything.
Try this code: http://danpeirce.net46.net/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=rpi_pic_led&#running_c_program_access_to_dev_ttyusb0_option_6
bwt what does lsusb tell you about arduino? is it a UNO or a 2009(FTDI?) there are now bug on the FTDI driver http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=8010

Comment: Thanks, lesto. It's an Arduino Leonardo, and there is no FTDI in dmesg output. lsusb is "Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2341:8036 Arduino SA Leonardo (CDC ACM, HID)". Tried that code from net46.net and it freezes on write() just the same :(

Comment: then the only way i see is to debug the USB driver of the raspi, you can start to sniff the usb with wireshark